# Django, save ModelForm

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have created a model **Student** which extends from the **Django User** and is a foreign key to another model while it has an integer field called year. What i'm trying to do is to save a form, which has 2 fields. The one is the **course id** and the another one is the the integer field **year**. When I'm clicking submit, i'm getting an error *Cannot assign "u'2'": "Student.course" must be a "Course" instance.*

models.py

```
class Student(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    course = models.ForeignKey(Course)
    year = models.IntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(1),
                                           MaxValueValidator(7)])
```

view.py

```
def step3(request):
    user = request.user
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SelectCourseYear(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return render_to_response("registration/complete.html", RequestContext(request))
    else:
        form = SelectCourseYear()
    return render(request, 'registration/step3.html',)
```

forms.py

```
class SelectCourseYear(forms.ModelForm):
    course = forms.CharField()
    year = forms.IntegerField(required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Student
        fields = ['user', 'course', 'year']
```

Comment: Could you try instead of `form.save()` write 3 lines of code: `obj = form.save(commit=False)`, `obj.course_id = request.POST['course']` and then `obj.save()`?

Comment: Tried it but still getting this error **Cannot assign "u'1'": "Student.course" must be a "Course" instance.**

Comment: where are you assigning the user's course? since I don't get the code where you are assigning the course attribute.

Comment: Well the student model has a 'course' foreign key to course model if that's what you mean.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

You dont need to redefine fields in the `ModelForm` if you've already mentioned them in the `fields` attribute. So your form should look like this -

```
class SelectCourseYear(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Student
        fields = ['course', 'year'] # removing user. we'll handle that in view
```

And we can handle the form with ease in the view -

```
def step3(request):
    user = request.user
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SelectCourseYear(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            student = form.save(commit=False)
            # commit=False tells Django that "Don't send this to database yet.
            # I have more things I want to do with it."

            student.user = request.user # Set the user object here
            student.save() # Now you can send it to DB

            return render_to_response("registration/complete.html", RequestContext(request))
    else:
        form = SelectCourseYear()
    return render(request, 'registration/step3.html',)
```

Comment: This does not work for me. I get a `NOT NULL constraint failed: appname_modelname.user_id` error when submitting this form for a user that doesn't have an instance of the model yet.

Comment: @Bibhas can you please help with a similiar issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55384218/how-to-bookmark-a-page-in-django

Comment: @Pieter, you have to do use commit = False, then you can attach user to your model then you .save() to to send to database. Don't try to form.save(commit=True) if you have relationship inside.

Answer (score 8):

`course` has to be an instance of a Course model, not just the primary key of the instance. You can still accept an id in the form as a text input, but you're going to need to retrieve the actual course instance and assign the value.

You'll need to verify that the course id is valid, so putting that code into the clean method isn't a bad idea. Notice also how the `course` field is excluded here? Otherwise the form will expect it to be present. You also don't need to re-define the year field, as the ModelForm will inherit that field from the Student model.

```
# forms.py

class SelectCourseYear(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Student
        exclude = ['user', 'course']

    course_id = forms.IntegerField()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.user = kwargs.pop('user')
        super(SelectCourseYear, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def clean_course_id(self):
        course_id = self.cleaned_data.get('course_id')
        try:
            self.course = Course.objects.get(pk=course_id)
        except Course.DoesNotExist:
            raise forms.ValidationError('Sorry, that course id is not valid.')

        return course_id

    def save(self, commit=True):
        instance = super(SelectCourseYear, self).save(commit=False)
        instance.course = self.course
        instance.user = self.user
        if commit:
            instance.save()
        return instance


# views.py

def step3(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SelectCourseYear(request.POST or None, user=request.user)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return render_to_response("registration/complete.html",
                RequestContext(request))
    return render(request, 'registration/step3.html',)
```

Now, when you call `.save()` on the model, the course field will be assigned an instance of `Course`

Comment: Unfortunately I'm getting an error saying **int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Course'**.

Comment: Sorry, that's my fault. I changed the field name from "course" to "course_id" to prevent a type collision, and forgot to update the clean method name.

Comment: Oh ok! Now it doesn't return an error but still it doesn't update the database. So in the admin panel both fields (course and year) are empty.

Comment: Let me add some extra code to ensure that the value gets set properly on the model.

Comment: Tried it but still no luck. Doesn't return an error but the database doesn't update. Any change that it matters that we don't use the 'user id' anywhere?

Comment: Also since it doesn't go to 'registration/complete.html', I guess the form isn't valid? It doesn't return an error but it just reloads step3.html

Comment: See my edits for how to pass in the user to the form.

Comment: Still the same. The form just reloads instead of going to `complete.html` so the form is not valid maybe? Also the db does not update. I guess I'm really stuck with this one?!

Comment: This is def a better approach. Use forms to create models entities. override save method. Now in every view you'll be using this form, you'll be adding the user.