# django ModelForm foreign key - text widget add if not exist

Tags: python, django, django-forms, modelform

I am just starting out with Django and have the following:

models.py:

```
class Song(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False, null=False)
    artist = models.ForeignKey(Artist, blank=False, null=False)

class Artist(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
```

Now I have a model form for Song but currently have no ability to add artists that don't already exist (rendered as a dropdown). It would be nice to allow users to add artists on the fly but haven't been able to find a way to get that working. I saw lots of answers relating to replicating the admin "add another..." but kept running into roadblocks and outdated information.

What I tried:

1. replicating the "add another" from the admin console
2. Creating as a regular form - but abandoned it because ModelForms gives me a lot for free
3. Started researching on formsets but got stuck there, could not find a working example

Is there a way to easily add another artist from the song form? I don't mind rendering a new textbox below the artist selection where the user can add a new artist but I don't know how to do that with ModelForms and then add the artist into the database before saving.

Any advice would be much appreciated!

Comment: Are you saying adding an artist while creating a song at the same time? "Add another artist" doesn't make much sense because you can only have one `ForeignKey` on each `Song`, right? If you want to create as many `Artist` as you want but not necessarily connecting to a `Song`, I suggest doing it separately, creating songs and creating artist are two different processes.

Comment: @ShangWang Sorry, apologies. "Add another" is a common term I've been seeing for "add an artist that doesn't exist and associate it with this song". Let's say I have no artists in my Artist table. I want to create a song, and associate it with Nirvana. I have to go to the artist form and add Nirvana as a new artist, then go back to the song form and select Nirvana from the dropdown. I want to be able to add Nirvana right there in the song form in the form of text or the little (+) sign that is often shown in the admin console

Comment: This is tricky, it's doable but might not be straight forward. You need to exclude `artist` in `Song` modelform, then create an `Artist` model form and pass both forms to the template together. You use javascript to show/hide the `Artist` depend on whether user wants to create a new artist or not. Then in your views.py you would save the `Artist` first, then do `song = song_form.save(commit=False)` and `song.artist = artist` then `song.save()`. For example you could see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22739701/django-save-modelform?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: Another way is to do a redirect when you click "+" artist button to the artist creation page, then when artist creation is done, redirect back to song creation page. You can control the redirection back to song creation page by adding a get parameter like `<artist_creation_url>/?from=<song_creation_url>`. However this would make user lose their previous unfinished data in the form.

Answer (score 0):

It would help to see what you are using to create your forms. I assume you are using a ModelFrom. If you are using jQuery I think you could use the following in your forms.py to capture a new artist. However, if you are using jQuery I would save individual forms as templates and display them as necessary depending on a button or link event for a new artist.

forms.py

```
class SongForm (forms.ModelForm):
    new_artist_name = forms.CharField()

    class Meta:
        model = Song

    def save(self, commit=True):
        # do something with self.cleaned_data['new_artist']
        new_artist = Artists.objects.filter('new_artist_name')
        if new_artist.exists():
            # Save song to artist.
        else:
            # Create and save new artist and save song to the
            # new artist.

        return super(SongForm, self).save(commit=commit)
```