# Django - how to submit a form from a ListView

Tags: python, django-2.0

I am trying to pass a form to a ListView in django to create a new object

Is there any way to do that?
(I know how to do that using def in stead of class)

Im using django 2.0 , python 3.4

This is the ListView:

```
class CustomerListView(ListView):
    template_name = 'customers/table_customers.html'
    context_object_name = 'items'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Customer.objects.all()

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(CustomerListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['form'] = CustomerForm
        return context
```

I can see the form in the page but when i hit "submit" i get a 405 response from the server: "Method Not Allowed (POST): /customers/customer/".

Here is the form:

```
class CustomerForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Customer
        fields = ['customer_name',
                'start_date', 
                'end_date',
                'team', 
                'status',
                'notes',  
                ]
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6406553/django-class-based-view-listview-with-form

Comment: @ChuckLaPress this solution seemed to work (i don't get the error anymore) but the  new customer isn't created

Comment: Can you show your CustomerForm ? and the html you are rendering the view to

Comment: yeah @ChuckLaPress

Comment: You should use [CreateView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#createview)

Comment: Great, now follow this example to have your form get save: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22739701/django-save-modelform