# Django not writing to database but print statements are working and updated

Tags: python, mysql, django, http

I am using Django as my Web framework. The relevant function is

```
def addWeight(request):
    if request.method == "GET":
        form = weightForm()
        return render(request, "base/weight.html", {"form": form})
    if request.method == "POST":
        try:
            form = weightForm(request.POST)
            if not form.is_valid():
                return HttpResponseBadRequest("Error with your form")
            data = form.cleaned_data
            day = macro_day.objects.get_or_create(owner=request.user, date=data["date"])
            print(data["weight"])
            day[0].weight = data["weight"]
            print(day[0])
            print(day[0].weight)
            return HttpResponse(status=204)`
```

```
<form action="weight" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <input type="submit" value="SUBMIT">
</form>
```

The form object is:

```
class weightForm(forms.Form):
    date = forms.DateField(label="Date")
    weight = forms.IntegerField(label="Weight", min_value=0, max_value=500)
```

day[0].weight reflects the value sent into the function by the webform but when I actually go into my database or call the object it appears that the change hasn't been made. I have another function implemented like this and I don't seem to have the same issue with it. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your code is incomplete. The missing exception handle might explain the the problem.

Comment: Did you expect the mere `day[0].weight = data["weight"]` to update your database?

Answer (score -1):

I think you missed to call form.save()

Otherwise data does not save to DB. Check this for details [formsave](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22739701/django-save-modelform)

Sample Code

```
def addWeight(request):
    if request.method == "GET":
        form = weightForm()
        return render(request, "base/weight.html", {"form": form})
    if request.method == "POST":
        try:
            form = weightForm(request.POST)
            if not form.is_valid():
                return HttpResponseBadRequest("Error with your form")
            data = form.cleaned_data
            day = macro_day.objects.get_or_create(owner=request.user, date=data["date"])
            print(data["weight"])
            day[0].weight = data["weight"]
            print(day[0])
            print(day[0].weight)
            form.save() ### saving form
            return HttpResponse(status=204)
```